# Use regex to get 2 specific groups of substring

Tags: java, regex, string

```
String s = #Section250342,Main,First/HS/12345/Jack/M,2000 10.00,
#Section250322,Main,First/HS/12345/Aaron/N,2000 17.00,
#Section250399,Main,First/HS/12345/Jimmy/N,2000 12.00,
#Section251234,Main,First/HS/12345/Jack/M,2000 11.00
```

Wherever there is the word /Jack/M in the3 string, I want to pull the section numbers(250342,251234) and the values(10.00,11.00) associated with it using regex each time.

I tried something like this https://regex101.com/r/4te0Lg/1 but it is still messed.

```
.Section(\d+(?:\.\d+)?).*/Jack/M
```

Answer (score 1):

If the only parts of each section that change are the section number, the name of the person and the last value (like in your example) then you can make a pattern very easily by using one of the sections where Jack appears and replacing the numbers you want by capturing groups.

Example:

```
#Section250342,Main,First/HS/12345/Jack/M,2000 10.00
```

becomes,

```
#Section(\d+),Main,First/HS/12345/Jack/M,2000 (\d+.\d{2})
```

If the section substring keeps the format but the other parts of it may change then just replace the rest like this:

```
#Section(\d+),\w+,(?:\w+/)*Jack/M,\d+ (\d+.\d{2})
```

I'm assuming that "Main" is a class, "First/HS/..." is a path and that the last value always has 2 and only 2 decimal places.

- \d - A digit: [0-9]
- \w - A word character: [a-zA-Z_0-9]
- + - one or more times
- * - zero or more times
- {2} - exactly 2 times
- () - a capturing group
- (?:) - a non-capturing group

For reference see: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

**Simple Java example on how to get the values from the capturing groups using java.util.regex.Pattern and java.util.regex.Matcher**

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class GetMatch {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s = "#Section250342,Main,First/HS/12345/Jack/M,2000 10.00,#Section250322,Main,First/HS/12345/Aaron/N,2000 17.00,#Section250399,Main,First/HS/12345/Jimmy/N,2000 12.00,#Section251234,Main,First/HS/12345/Jack/M,2000 11.00";
        
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("#Section(\\d+),\\w+,(?:\\w+/)*Jack/M,\\d+ (\\d+.\\d{2})");
        Matcher m;
        String[] tokens = s.split(",(?=#)"); //split the sections into different strings
        
        for(String t : tokens) //checks every string that we got with the split
        {   
            m = p.matcher(t);
            if(m.matches()) //if the string matches the pattern then print the capturing groups
                System.out.printf("Section: %s, Value: %s\n", m.group(1), m.group(2));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use 2 capture groups, and use a [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30900794/5424988) approach to not cross `@Section` followed by a digit.

```
#Section(\d+)(?:(?!#Section\d).)*\bJack/M,\d+\h+(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\b
```

**Explanation**

- `#Section(\d+)` Match #Section and capture 1+ digits in **group 1**
- `(?:(?!#Section\d).)*` Match any character if not directly followed by #Section and a digit
- `\bJack/M,` Match the word Jack and `/M,`
- `\d+\h+` Match 1+ digits and 1+ spaces
- `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` Capture **group 2**, match 1+ digits and an optional decimal part
- `\b` A word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/myOQPw/1)

In Java:

```
String regex = "#Section(\\d+)(?:(?!#Section\\d).)*\\bJack/M,\\d+\\h+(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)\\b";
```